# I want to rename all files in a directory from *.ts to *.mkv

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

Rename all the files in .ts files in a directory
My echo command works but not if I try to make it a new variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "${1}"/*.ts; do
  echo ${file} | sed -e 's|.ts|.mkv|'
  new_name=${file} | sed -e 's|.ts|.mkv|'
done
```

Comment: Just use `rename`. If the Perl version, it's just `rename 's/.ts$/.mkv' *`.

Comment: I want to save the renamed file to a variable to pass in another command in the script (input name -> output name).  The examples are for renaming them in the directory

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Are your files named with `.ts` actually Matroska files?  Why are they all misnamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to tell you to change the assignment to:

```
new_name=$( echo ${file} | sed -e 's|.ts|.mkv|' )
```

But a better solution would be to do:

```
new_name="${file%.ts}.mkv"
```

Comment: the 1st option works the second give file.mkv/*.mkv

Comment: If the loop is applied only to files in `"${1}"/*.ts` I don't see how a `.mkv` file gets in the list. @NasKar

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.ts' -exec rename .ts .mkv {} "+"
```

Run this in the directory containing the `.ts` files.

Answer (score 0):

`rename` is what you're looking for :

```
rename '.ts' '.mkv' "${1}/*.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `$file` unquoted in your code, you invite the shell to split its contents into words based on the value of `$IFS` (space, tab and newline by default). Those words would then undergo filename expansion if they contained any globbing patterns.

By using `echo`, you would possibly also expand backslash sequences like `\n` and `\t` depending on what shell options happened to be set (`xpg_echo`).

Your first `sed` command would replace any character followed by `ts` in the filename with `.mkv`.  This means that the filename `bats.ts` would be changed to `b.mkv.ts`.

The second line in the loop is nonsensical, as it takes the output of an assignment and passes it to `sed` over a pipe.

Assigning the output of a command to a variable is done with command substitutions:

```
variable=$( some_command )
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in "$1"/*.ts; do
    mv -i "$name" "${name%.ts}.mkv"
done
```

This would loop over all files having a filename suffix of `.ts` in the directory given by `"$1"`.  Each file would be renamed to the same name, but with the `.ts` filename suffix removed and the `.mkv` suffix inserted at the end of the filename.

The variable substitution `${variable%pattern}` would remove the shortest suffix in `$variable` that matches `pattern`.  This would work even if the filename happened to contain embedded newlines.

By using `mv -i` we hopefully prevent the function from accidentally overwriting existing files.  Another way to do that would be to do something like

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in "$1"/*.ts; do
    newname=${name%.ts}.mkv
    if [ ! -e "$newname" ]; then
        mv "$name" "$newname"
    else
        printf 'Name "%s" is already taken\n' "$newname" >&2
    fi
done
```

In addition to this test, you may actually want to check whether `$name` exists to start with.  If the pattern `"$1"/.*ts` does not match any filenames, then it would by default remain unexpanded.  We can catch that with

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in "$1"/*.ts; do
    [ ! -e "$name" ] && break

    newname=${name%.ts}.mkv
    if [ ! -e "$newname" ]; then
        mv "$name" "$newname"
    else
        printf 'Name "%s" is already taken\n' "$newname" >&2
    fi
done
```

In the `bash` shell, you could use `shopt -s nullglob` to make nonmatching patterns expand to nothing instead.  In `bash` you may also want to use `shopt -s dotglob` if you want to additionally match hidden filenames.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "${1}"/*.ts; do
   mv "${file}" "$(basename "${file}").mkv"
done
```

Comment: Pleasee not that if you want `basename` to remove the `.ts` suffix, you will need to specify that with an option and provide the suffix to remove explicitly (at least in those implementations of `basename` I have come across so far).

Comment: This will also remove the directory from the `mv` target, so the new files will end up in the current directory.